# JSON nested condition failing

Tags: json, conditional-statements

### Following JSON is failing with error Parse error on line 1:
...Sub_level": { "${if((user?.reg

Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

```
\\\ "sub_level": { "${if((user?.region!=null)||(user.region.equals('AMER'))|| 
   (user.region.equals('APAC'))) {'1'} else if(user.region.equals('EMEA)){'4'} else {'1'}}"}
  \\\
```

Comment: How else would you write this condition

Comment: Basically I need script for the condition
Sub_level is 1 if user.region is 'AMER' or 'APAC'
Sub_level is 4 if user.region is 'EMEA'
Sub_level is 1 if user.region is other